# Is there any evidence for/against the existence of Jungian archetypes?

Tags: evolution, cross-cultural-psychology, jung

I was shocked to be unable to find any systematic reviews on the relevance of Jung and particulary his archetypes. In my search, I usually encountered criticism based on definitions too loose to be properly debunked but I think the concept of archetypes as "distinct universal personalities in our brain" is quite a falsifiable one.

I find [Tom Boardsman's SE answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/what-form-might-jungian-archetypes-take-in-the-brain/1179#1179) to a theoretical question on the archetypes really interesting and I think it does provide an argument against the archetypes as Jung described them - as literal images - from what I've gathered, automatic visual detection is pretty rare in humans and can be found only in a few areas such as face recognition or [snake detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_detection_theory). Jung's idea of such images made a lot more sense to me when I found out it was likely influenced by [lamarckism](https://sci-hub.se/10.1177/000306519204000210). But - of course - my layman notion is far from a proof.

However, I imagine Jung's archetypes could be best put to a test by a cross-cultural comparison of dreams. Sadly, I haven't found any study that would take this challenge seriously. A bit less exact way could be cross-cultural comparison of narratives for behavioral patterns. In that regard, I have only found [mentions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10595468_The_Relevance_of_Jungian_Psychology_for_Cultural_Psychiatry) of criticism of the remarks on the very non-Western cultures that influenced Jung.

So are there any studies which would provide some basic evidence for or against the existence of Jungian archetypes?

Comment: Related: [Scientific legacy of Carl Jung (and of analytical psychology)?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/18812/7001), [Is there a reasonable scientific backing for Carl Jung's type theories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13027/7001)